# solving the questions of project euler from python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I am new to programming. I am solving [Project Euler Question 12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12):

> The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. The first ten terms would be:
>
> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
>
> Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:
>
> 1: 1  3: 1,3  6: 1,2,3,6 10: 1,2,5,10 15: 1,3,5,15 21: 1,3,7,21 28: 1,2,4,7,14,28 We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.
>
> What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

My solution is:

```
import math  
k=0  
count=0  
for i in range (1,100000):   
    k+=i  
    a=int(math.sqrt(k))+1
    count=0
    for j in range (1,a):  
        n=a%j  
        if n==0:  
           count=count+1  
           count*=2  
           if count>500:  
              print'',count  
              break
```

For `count>100` and numbers less than 100 it gives the output quickly,
but for 500 it takes a long time. How can I reduce the time of execution?

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0
count = 0
while count < 501:
    i+=1
    count = 0
    tNum = (i*(i + 1)) / 2
    y=int(tNum**0.5)
    for j in range(1,y + 1):
        if tNum % j==0 :
            count+=2
        if y ** 2 == tNum:
            count-=1
print(tNum)
```

Comment: Please explain your code rather than just a block of it

Comment: T num=(n*(n+1))/2.It is about the divisors.Lets take the 10.The integer part of the sqrt of number 10 is 3. If we use an algo using for loop to get the divisors. Lets add 2 to the variable count if 10%i(for i in range(1,int(10)**.5+1))we get 4 as the answer. 10=2*5 and the number of divisors should be 2*2=4(take the powers of the prime factorization and then add 1 to them and multiply them.But what happen if you take 9? 9=3^2 and have 3 divisors.If you use the above algo the count would be 4.So U have to reduce 1 from count if (sqrt(num)) ^ 2==num

Answer (score -1):

Only use odd numbers.

```
for j in range (1,a, 2):
```

Should be twice as fast.

You could also save all known prime numbers to a list and only go through this list to test with %.

Comment: "all known prime numbers".  That's a pretty long list...OP is looking for all factors.  They can be even.